# Mysql query: match against using wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table named 'acts' which has 3 columns which are indexed together:

```
act_name, short_description, main_description
```

Within the table, one row has an act named 'red riot'

When I execute the following search, red riot appears in the results:

```
SELECT * from acts where MATCH(act_name, short_description, main_description) AGAINST ('*r*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Yet if I expand on that, and search for `*re*` it returns no results:

```
SELECT * from acts where MATCH(act_name, short_description, main_description) AGAINST ('*re*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Why is that? Is there a better way to use wildcards in match against queries?

I have tried changing `*` to `%` but this returns no results on either query.

Comment: Do >= 50% of your records contain `re`?

Comment: *words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match*

Comment: How could r work and not re if >50 case is true?

Comment: There are only 42 records in the table and no. If i change the search to 'red' there is only 1 potential match and it does not show in results

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<del>The value "re" is a stopword for MATCH() searches.</del>

<del>http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html</del>

[edit]

It's true that "re" is a stopword, but the actual reason this wasn't working was because fulltext searching excludes words in the source material whose length is less than the value of the system variable ft_min_word_len (whose default value is 4).

So searching for "red*" will find records containing "redder" and "reddest", but not "red".

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16d442/1

Comment: Note also that the "\*re\*" syntax you're trying to use is incorrect.  The "\*" operator only applies to the end of the keyword, so "re\*" is the correct syntax.  Searching for "\*iot", for example, is invalid, and will not match a record that contains "riot".

Comment: ok... adjusting the query to 'red*', or simply 'red' also fails which is not a stop word or the latter using wildcards - I suspect there's something else missing here

Comment: OK, it looks like fulltext indexing simply doesn't index words in the original source that have length less than the ft_min_word_len variable (whose default value is 4).  So searching for "red" or "red\*" (or any three-letter word) will not find records that have "red" in the source (but it will find "reddit", "redding", etc).  Searching for "riot", on the other hand, will find your record.  The reason that your original "r\*" query worked is because it was matching against "riot", not "red".

Here's a fiddle I put together to examine this matching logic: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16d442/1/0

Comment: Excellent explanation, many thanks - I knew about this setting but haven't had need to change it for years and simply forgot! Thank you