# Match Against MYSQL returns SSAT but not SAT

Tags: mysql, search, match

I have a column with the names SAT, and SSAT. In my sql query:

```
"...AND (MATCH (s.subject_en_name, s.subject_ch_name) AGAINST ('".$search."')..."
```

I get results when typing in SSAT (including results mentioning both SAT and SSAT), but I get zero results when I type in just SAT.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From other questions, I think it has to do with the min-length search: [mysqld] ft_min_word_len

[Mysql query: match against using wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777359/mysql-query-match-against-using-wildcard)