# MySQL 5.7 miss matching against two-Chinese-character words

Tags: mysql, sql, chinese-locale, multibyte-characters

Table tb:

```
title                       keywords
企业贷款，该如何看懂银行流水     出口退税,贷款,现金流量表,利润表
最高人民法院关于审理民间        企业贷款,合同法,贷款
中国宏观经济数据点评           企业贷款,贷款

ngram_token_size=2
FULLTEXT INDEX `keywords_title`(`keywords`, `title`)
```

Now I match keywords and title with a four-Chinese-character word '企业贷款'

```
select * from tb where MATCH (keywords, title) AGAINST ('企业贷款');

|[
title                       keywords
企业贷款，该如何看懂银行流水     出口退税,贷款,现金流量表,利润表
最高人民法院关于审理民间        企业贷款,合同法,贷款
中国宏观经济数据点评           企业贷款,贷款
]|
```

But When I match them with a two-chinese-character word '贷款', no result matched.

```
select * from tb where MATCH (keywords, title) AGAINST ('贷款');
|[
]|
```

Comment: Can you add only "贷款" word comma separated and test query again? "贷款" word is not present in MATCH

Comment: still no result matched

Comment: TRY https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777359/mysql-query-match-against-using-wildcard

Comment: Use wild card as mentioned in post

Comment: select * from tb where MATCH (keywords, title) AGAINST ('*贷款' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Comment: What's the point of a FULL TEXT index if wildcards are necessary?

Comment: It's because full text searches are "natural language" searches by default, meaning it matches based on "full words", not sub-strings of words. I tested with your data but replacing `企业贷款` with `test`. `MATCH (keywords, title) AGAINST ('test')` returns the same results, but `MATCH (keywords, title) AGAINST ('est')` returns no results. So this is not multibyte-specific.

Comment: @MangeshSathe - Full text searches don't support prepended wildcards. Your suggestion won't work. Nothing will work. This is working by design. Full Text searches don't do partial-string matches, as it is a "natural language" search. To achieve stated goal, `LIKE` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tb
DROP INDEX `keywords_title ` ,
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `keywords_title ` (`keywords` ASC, `title` ASC)  /*!70000 WITH PARSER `ngram` */
```

`/*!70000 WITH PARSER`ngram`*/`  is necessary!

Answer (score 0):

```
/*!70000 WITH PARSER ngram*/
```

It mean the syntax will only be executed when the MySQL version >= 7.0.0, so you didn't use the ngram parser at all.

In my advice, you still need to use the ngram parser, because the default full-text parser can't handle the Chinese string well (This also mentioned in the [document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-restrictions.html)).

I ran some tests on MySQL 5.7 & 8.0 server, got same results:

### For **MyISAM**

```
X: return empty result  O: return rows contain the pattern

built-in parser
  IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE (default)
    企业贷款    X
    贷款        X
  IN BOOLEAN MODE
    企业贷款    O
    贷款        X

ngram
  IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE (default)
    企业贷款    X
    贷款        X
  IN BOOLEAN MODE
    企业贷款    O
    贷款        O
```

### For **InnoDB**

```
built-in parser
  IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE (default)
    企业贷款    O
    贷款        X
  IN BOOLEAN MODE
    企业贷款    O
    贷款        X
ngram
  IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE (default)
    企业贷款    O
    贷款        O
  IN BOOLEAN MODE
    企业贷款    O
    贷款        O
```

First, if you search **in natural language mode**, there is a 50% threshold in MyISAM engine. Both `企业贷款` and `贷款` occur in more than half of the rows, MySQL will treat them as stopwords ([doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)), so it return nothing.

Next, if you use the built-in parser, it causes strange results, since the parser can't process these ideographic languages well.

There are two reasons for your situation:

1. Not like ngram, the built-in parser only can use some symbols (in this case, is comma) to parse a Chinese sentence. The parser only catches `企业贷款` token and doesn't catch it's sub-string `贷款`.
2. The built-in parser treats a Chinese token in the same way as it treats an English token. The length of `贷款` is smaller than the minimum length of a word that considered to index (check `ft_min_word_len` setting for MyISAM, `innodb_ft_min_token_size` for InnoDB), so it will not be indexed even though `贷款` occurs in the `keywords` field many times.

Answer (score 0):

The MYSQL document explains the purpose of [ngram Full-Text Parser](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html)

> The built-in MySQL full-text parser **uses the white space between words
> as a delimiter** to determine where words begin and end, which is a
> limitation when working with ideographic languages that do not use
> word delimiters. **To address this limitation**, MySQL provides an ngram
> full-text parser that supports Chinese, Japanese, and Korean (CJK).

`ngram_token_size=2` (the default value) let you search the 2 characters Chinese words in your case.

`/*!70000 WITH PARSER` ngram `*/` means if MySQL version >= 7.0.0 executes it. FTS was introduced in mysql 5.6, so `/*!50600 WITH PARSER` ngram `*/` should be enough.